# Fallo al mover carpetas

Tags: batch

Estaba creando una serie de batchs para ordenar los archivos de mi compu que siempre es un desorden.

Todo me funciona de maravilla excepto una cosa, mover la carpeta de archivos de los html.

```
echo off
color 0a
set elementos=11
:loop
set /a resultado=%resultado% + 1
if %resultado%==1 (cd "%userprofile%\Downloads")
if %resultado%==2 (cd "%userprofile%\Desktop\Carpeta sin titulo")
if %resultado%==3 (cd "%userprofile%\Desktop\Nueva carpeta")
if %resultado%==4 (cd "%userprofile%\Desktop\Celu")
if %resultado%==5 (cd "%userprofile%\Desktop\Celu\Download")
if %resultado%==6 (cd "%userprofile%\Desktop\Celu\WhatsApp\Media\GBWhatsApp Documents")
if %resultado%==7 (cd "%userprofile%\Desktop\Celu\WhatsApp\Media\WhatsApp Documents")
if %resultado%==8 (cd "%userprofile%\Desktop\Celu\Telegram\Telegram Documents")
if %resultado%==9 (cd "%userprofile%\Documents\MEGA")
if %resultado%==10 (cd "%userprofile%\Documents\MEGAsync Downloads")
if %resultado%==11 (cd "%userprofile%\Desktop")
     . . .
move de varios archivos
     . . .
move "*.htm" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Archivos\html"
move "*.html" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Archivos\html"
move "*_archivos" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Archivos\html"
move "*_files" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Archivos\html"
if %resultado%==%elementos% (goto :exit)
goto :loop
:exit
cd "%userprofile%\Desktop"
echo n | move /-y "*.*" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Archivos"
```

En este batch hago un loop moviendome en los distintos directorios donde necesito reubicar y ordenar los archivos.

El problema surge cuando intento mover *_files y *_archivos, no me lee esas carpetas y por ende no las mueve.

No tengo idea de porque no las lee, si alguien sabe el porque y me puede ayudar se lo agradeceria.

Answer (score 0):

*_files y *_archivos son carpetas y quieres moverlos a Archivos usando esta instrucción:

```
echo n | move /-y "*.*" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Archivos"
```

Tal vez si pones algo como esto abajo así:

```
echo n | move /-y "*.*" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Archivos"
move %userprofile%\Downloads\_files %userprofile%\Desktop\Archivos\_files
```

Comment: no, la parte que trato de mover las carpetas de html es esta

    move "*_archivos" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Archivos\html"
    move "*_files" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Archivos\html"

Answer (score 0):

casi lo acabo de solucionar hace un rato usando un for
cuando lo pongo en el cmd funciona

```
FOR /D %x in (*_archivos) DO move "%x" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Archivos\html"
FOR /D %x in (*_files) DO move "%x" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Archivos\html"
```

pero cuando lo paso para el bat no funciona

```
FOR /D %%x in (*_archivos) DO move "%%x" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Archivos\html"
FOR /D %%x in (*_files) DO move "%%x" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Archivos\html"
```